# Какой утилитой можно проверить совместимость проекта на PHP 7.4 c PHP 8.0

Tags: php

Есть ли какие авточекеры \ стат анализаторы, которые скажут где проект сломается если поменять версию с 7.4 на 8.0\8.1

Comment: PhpStorm подсветит файлы красной линией где найдёт ошибки

Comment: Легче скачать, локально поставить 8.0 и смотреть сыплющиеся ошибки. Смотреть и исправлять, если целью является именно это).

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь [CodeSniffer от Squizlabs](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer в связке с [модулем проверки на совместимость](https://github.com/PHPCompatibility/PHPCompatibility)

Позволяет проверять на соместимость с любой версией PHP. Плюс есть ряд настроек, которые позволяют делать проверку более гибко.